# CSS, Rotated div makes page horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transforms, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to design a footer for my website like this:

[image]

but I've got this result, causing a horizontal scroll (red background is for better showing the problem)

[image]

```css
.footer-container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.rotate-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.rotate-white {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: -40px;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

.rotate-grey {
  top: -40px;
  right: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: -2;
}

.footer-top-img {
  width: 290px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  right: auto;
  top: -140px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<footer style="margin-top: 150px;">
  <div class="footer-container px-xl-5 w-100">
    <div class="rotate-container">
      <div class="rotate-white"></div>
      <div class="rotate-grey"></div>
    </div>
    <img class="footer-top-img d-xl-block d-none" src="../global/imgs/footer/footertop.png" />
    <div class="container-fluid footer-content px-xl-5">
      . . .
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer/>
```

How can I remove the overflow of the red div to prevent the page from scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Therefor, you need to hide the oferflow of the body itself with

```css
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: overflow-x not working, just removes the scrollbar. doesn't hide the side of the red Div.

Comment: Yeah, that was your question.
If the overflowing part of the red box should be hidden, you need to apply the `overflow-x: hidden` on one of the parental containers.